# Getting polygon boundaries of City in JSON from Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api

When searching Google Maps for a city, the city's administrative boundary is displayed.

[image]

Is there a way to get the polygon boundaries of City in a JSON format using google maps api?

Comment: Related post: [Which API method provides the drawing of a city's boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639198/which-api-method-provides-the-drawing-of-a-citys-boundaries)

Comment: @ArMoraer your related post is a dead end

Comment: The format for Google map is GeoJson. There is an API for querying by zipcodes,city and state  ,  www.boundaries-io.com

Answer (score 88):

You can get polygon coordenates in json for using with googlemaps using openstreetmap.
Go to http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/
search a place like "Partido de Ituzaingó"

click on "details"

Look for OSM ID and copy it (control+c), example: 2018776

paste the ID in 
http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py
and download the polygon

Comment: http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py not work anymore. you can use http://global.mapit.mysociety.org

Comment: global.mapit.mysociety.org didn't work for Baghdad (but the original post did): first I got it here: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=179724619, then found the relation id to be `5638803`, when I run http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/code/osm_rel/5638803 I get `{"code": 404, "error": "No areas were found that matched code osm_rel = 5638803."}`

Comment: Too complicated. And didn't work for me. its easier to grab the geojson directly from the  nominatim's source code.

Answer (score 37):

To get polygon boundaries just add `format=json` to your request!

So instead of 
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Warsaw+Poland&polygon_geojson=1

use

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Warsaw+Poland&polygon_geojson=1&format=json

By adding &format=geojson you can get a valid geojson response

Comment: Thanks, I would like to download the boundaries of all neighbourhood within a city? Is this also doable and what is the command for that?

Answer (score 10):

I've found a work around solution for this problem.

1. Go to [www.gadm.org/country](http://www.gadm.org/country)
2. Choose your country and **select Google Earth .kmz file format**
3. Choose the level you need (level 3 is the deepest with all small towns/cities)
4. Download the file (can be large)
5. Unzip the .kmz file (You'll find a .kml which is XML)
6. Open it with Sublime or notepad++ (the file will probably be too large for other text editor)
7. Search by city name and copy data below (Search can take 1 to 4 seconds with large file)

You can use lat,long data and parse it into an array.
This solution is working well, but the quality of the path is sometimes rough.

Comment: Excellent tip thanks. I've made a basic repo with PHP and javascript to automate much of this herE: https://github.com/andyg2/parse-gadm-kml/

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to steal Google's data. May be you could look at [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) which is designed for people to download.

Comment: Have some exemple, how can extract polygons boundaries in OpenStreetMap? If I extract this, can draw the extracted polygon on google maps?

Comment: Please search this site and ask a new question if you are unable to find the answer to this

Comment: Who would consider this stealing? This data is taken from the US Census.

Comment: then fetch it from the US census site, though I doubt they have many UK city boundaries

Comment: There is no mention about stealing anything in the question

Comment: Google's data is proprietary, circumventing their terms of service to download data that is freely available elsewhere is stealing in most jurisdictions.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Google Maps API, OpenStreetMap may help you to search for a city by name in this page 
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ . Then review search results, and you can get region coordinate in GeoJSON format
e.g (http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=145126778) to get mashhad geojson coordinates in Administrative tab