# How to export Google Maps zip polygon to shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-maps

I have the following [URL](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rochester,+NY+14621/@43.1931576,-77.6120501,13z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x89d6b5d3dcb7fde5:0xe5f7401ba01c33c8!8m2!3d43.1874752!4d-77.6020569) that is a zip polygon from Google Maps that I want to export to shapefile and open in QGIS. How can I do that?

Comment: Is it a kmz file? These can be opened in qgis and saved as shapefiles.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183248/getting-polygon-boundaries-of-city-in-json-from-google-maps-api and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297117/zip-code-boundaries-using-google-maps-api