# Getting JSON data from Google Maps

Tags: geojson, google-maps, json, nominatim

I have reviewed [Getting polygon boundaries of City in JSON from Google Maps API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/183248/176211) as well as the answers by [german_martin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192298/176211) and [Kamil Latosinski](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/284305/176211). There are two critical weaknesses in Nominatim, using Malaysia as a case study:

**1) The polygons include water (left = Nominatim, right = Google Maps)**

[image]

Above are searches for 'Selangor'. I am aware that the boundary over water is the true administrative boundary, but for most visualisation exercises, this would make it look quite weird.

**2) Postcode-level data is very coarse, at least for Msia (left = Nominatim, right = Google Maps)**

[image]

Above are searches for '11900, Penang'. Nominatim just doesn't have it.

---

So, you can see why I really need to extract the JSON from Google Maps.

Does anyone know how to do this, preferably programatically so I can iterate over 2000 postcodes?

However, if it requires manual effort, I'm willing to do it.

Comment: Just because you don't like the answer doesn't make this a new question - there is no way to steal Google's data.

Comment: @IanTurton that wasn't my attention so much as wondering if new techniques were available. Do you know if it's possible to pay for it? I'm not necessarily after a free solution.